# Is there any official way of obtaining ISO 3166-2 codes?

Tags: iso

I know that ISO 3166-2 standard contains the list of regions in countries (however those regions are called).
But other than the fact that a full list is available on Wikipedia I cannot find any official JSON/XML/CSV/... file containing the standard.
I would assume that [www.iso.org](http://www.iso.org) would have an API providing this file but did not find any.

Is there any official way of obtaining that file, similar to how `thephpleague/iso3166` is the official way of obtaining ISO 3166-1?

Comment: Since when is `thephpleague/iso3166` ‘the official way of obtaining `ISO 3166-1`’? What even is `thephpleague/iso3166`?

Comment: maybe the question should be more like "Is there an alternative to the official way of obtaining iso3166-2?" as the ISO website states official methods as described by @motto

Answer (score 5):

Per the ISO website, the official way to obtain ISO 3166 codes is the [Country Codes Collection](https://www.iso.org/publication/PUB500001.html), which contains the codes from parts 1, 2 and 3 of ISO 3166 in XML, CSV and XLS formats. As it is a product (selling standards is big money!) it will set you back 300 CHF (~$USD340).

They do however allow you to [preview the codes](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:pub:PUB500001:en) or search the codes on their [Online Browsing Platform (OBP)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search), and as the dataset is quite small you will find the whole thing represented by the sample.

The OBP also allows you to sign up for notifications to be informed when changes are made.

So far as an "official way of obtaining the file" is concerned, that/those would be it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the UN Statistics Division M49 standard. it is available as csv or excel data. It includes ISO-alpha-2, ISO-alpha-3 codes and much more. It is actually listed as a reference in the bibliography for both ISO 3166-1:2020 and 3166-2:2020. (the bibliography is available to read free of charge via the document preview)

The bibliography states that this link provides up to date information.

https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/

you will want to click the "Full View" option or append "overview/" to the previous link.